# Propagating events between applications

Tags: event-sourcing

For a long time our time is discussing about propagating global events between applications that could (but don't have to) be on different servers. We have few solutions but we can't find perfect one.

**Background:** Suppose there are **Application A**, **Application B** and **Application C** where *Application A* can be an app accessible for a user, e.g. a shop with books and *Application B* is an app for creating reports in real time  and *Application C* is a tool for aggregating sales reports from internet book shops and stationary shops (some kind of CRM). This is not how our infrastructure looks like, this is just an example.

**Scenario:** User buys a book from *Application A* which causes adding an order into user account. *Application A* creates an event, e.g. `book:bought` **only once** with information about purchase.

**Expected:**

1. *Application B* listens to `book:bought`-type events from anywhere. When `book:bought` event is being dispatched, the app generates a report.
2. *Application C* also listens to `book:bought`-type events from anywhere. When `book:bought` event is sent, the app creates a sale and order record.

**Question:** How do you handle such situations? Do you have any pub-sub mechanism? How do you handle infrastructure or network problems? What if one of nodes (like *Application B* and *Application C*) is down? Is there any reliable patterns and tools to use?

Many thanks for any advice!

**PS.** Yes, I looked for similar questions, I've found some but very often they are related with propagating events in **one application**. I've also found such pattern: http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/MessageBus.html but I would to hear from you is it reliable enough and how to make sure that propagated event will be consumed later if the application is down.

Comment: Ok, you already found the "MessageBus" enterprise pattern, and if you use Google, you will find also some available products/architectures for this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722675/implementing-a-message-bus-architecture. So your question boils down to if those products are reliable, or if it makes sense to implement your own. But a question about third party tools would be very off-topic here on this site, and a question if you should implement your own, too.

Comment: I heard from my friends about the use of RabbitMQ API. https://www.rabbitmq.com . It does have the concept of pub-sub model.